# EntityFramework trying to insert unchanged attached entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have model like this:

```
public class Parent
{
    public ChildA ChildA { get; set;}
    public ChildB ChildB { get; set;}
}
```

In my cache I store collection of such objects for statistics. When I'm trying to save this collection, I get error that ChildA cannot be added as it is violation primary key constaint.

```
            ICollection<Metric> statistics = this.cacheService.Get<ICollection<Metric>>(statisticsCacheKey);
            if (statistics.Any())
            {
                foreach (Parent parent in statistics)
                {
                    this.dataService.Attach<ChildA>(parent.ChildA);
                    this.dataService.Attach<ChildB>(parent.ChildB);

                    this.parentRepository.Create(parent);
                }

                await this.dataService.SaveChangesAsync();
                statistics.Clear();
                this.cacheService.Put<ICollection<Parent>>(statisticsCacheKey, statistics);
            }
```

ChildA exists in the database and it is attached to the context, so I don't get why EF is trying to insert it.
My attach method looks like this

```
public void Attach<T>(T entity)
        where T : class, IEntity
    {
        EntityState state = context.Entry<T>(entity).State;
        if (state == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            IEnumerable<T> local = (IEnumerable<T>)context.Set<T>().Local;
            bool alreadyAtContext = local.Contains(entity, new EntityComparer());
            if (!alreadyAtContext)
            {
                context.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```